# Unexpected response to .val() jQuery by samsung s7 device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a password masking function and am using .val() jQuery to replace the content of text-field with "*", the function is responding correctly as expected for all the other devices, but only for Samsung S7 the content passed as argument for .val() is getting appended to the value of text-field. Is there any alternative to .val() jQuery which can replace the content of text-field in samsung s7 also or please somebody suggest a solution what can be done for correcting this issue?
For eg: If I start typing "Welcome1" in the text-field the value getting stored in the text-field goes like:
"W" for "W", but "WWe" for "We"

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel. Just use `<input type="password">` for masked input, which will behave consistenly across browsers.

Try plain JS also - instead of jQuery methods:

```
var content = input.val() // read
input.val('New content') // write
```

try plain JS approach:

```
var content = input.value // read
input.value = 'New content' // write
```

Comment: But is there a way to address the mentioned issue?! @Waldemarlce